# Need pandas code that converts a df with multiple samples to run a box plot

Tags: python, pandas, biopython

I am writing a script to make box plots from some RNA-Seq data.

The pseudo-code

```
1. Select a row based on gene name 
2. make a column for each type of cell 
3. make box plot
```

I have 1 and 3 down

```
df2 = df[df[0].str.match("TCAP")]
????
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.box(df,x="CellType",y = "Expression",title = "GENE")
fig.show()
```

The code needs to convert the following tables

```
Gene    Celltype-1_#1  Celltype-1_#2  Celltype-1_#3  Celltype-2_#1  Celltype-2_#2  Celltype-2_#3

A          1                1              1              3              3            3
B          5                5              5              4              4            4
```

to this Using: df2 = df[df[0].str.match("TCAP")]

```
 Gene    Celltype-1_#1  Celltype-1_#2  Celltype-1_#3  Celltype-2_#1  Celltype-2_#2  Celltype-2_#3

    A          1                1              1              3              3            3
```

Then i need code to make it into this

```
Gene  CellType   Expression    

 A       1           1

 A       1           1

 A       1           1

 A       2           3

 A       2           3

 A       2           3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [DataFrame.stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) method for this kind of transformation.

```
# need to have an index to make stack work
df = df.set_index('Gene')

# stack returns a series here
df = df.stack().to_frame().reset_index()

# At this point we have:
#     Gene        level_1  0
#  0     A  Celltype-1_#1  1
#  1     A  Celltype-1_#2  1
#  2     A  Celltype-1_#3  1
#  3     A  Celltype-2_#1  3
#  4     A  Celltype-2_#2  3
#  5     A  Celltype-2_#3  3
#  6     B  Celltype-1_#1  5
#  7     B  Celltype-1_#2  5
#  8     B  Celltype-1_#3  5
#  9     B  Celltype-2_#1  4
#  10    B  Celltype-2_#2  4
#  11    B  Celltype-2_#3  4

df.columns = ['Gene', 'Celltype', 'Expression']

# optionally rename values in celltype column
df['Celltype'] = df['Celltype'].apply(lambda t: t[9:10])

# now you can select by Gene or any other columns and pass to Plotly:
print(df[df['Gene'] == 'A'])

#     Gene Celltype  Expression
#  0     A        1           1
#  1     A        1           1
#  2     A        1           1
#  3     A        2           3
#  4     A        2           3
#  5     A        2           3
```

Note that by stacking the whole dataframe upfront, it's now simple to select multiple genes at once and pass them to Plotly together:

```
df_many = df[df['Gene'].isin(['A', 'B'])]
```

Comment: Works Beautifully